# Laravel Sail problem "no configuration file provided: not found"

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu

trying to launch a laravel project with sail:

```
~/Documents/__laravel_projects/testApp$ ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

I get this error message:

```
no configuration file provided: not found
```

versions: Ubuntu 22.04, Laravel Framework 9.20.0, Docker Desktop 4.10.1

Does anyone know how to fix the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved thanks to @signorpiero [ref](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sail-problem-no-configuration-file-provided-not-found?page=1&replyId=811828).

My solution: From project path execute these two instructions:

1. **php artisan sail:install**

   ```
   ~/Documents/__laravel_projects/testApp$ php artisan sail:install
   ...
   ```
2. **./vendor/bin/sail up**:

   ```
   ~/Documents/__laravel_projects/testApp$ ./vendor/bin/sail up
   ...
   [+] Running 12/13
   ...
   ```

Comment: you link to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sail-problem-no-configuration-file-provided-not-found?page=1&replyId=811828 saved me tons of time researching.

Answer (score 1):

Add docker-compose.yml into your root directory, the content will be like below:

```
    # For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
    version: '3'
    services:
        laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
        mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
        redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    networks:
        sail:
        driver: bridge
    volumes:
        sail-mysql:
        driver: local
        sail-redis:
        driver: local
```

Comment: Please add a little more context on why this works - is it replacing a Docker Compose file that should have been present in the default installation of Laravel (Sail)?